# embedding word positions in keras

Tags: python, nlp, keras, word2vec, word-embedding

I am trying to build a relation extraction system for drug-drug interactions using a CNN and need to make embeddings for the words in my sentences. The plan is to represent each word in the sentences as a combination of 3 embeddings: (w2v,dist1,dist2) where w2v is a pretrained word2vec embedding and dist1 and dist2 are the relative distances between each word in the sentence and the two drugs that are possibly related.

I am confused about how I should approach the issue of padding so that every sentence is of equal length. Should I pad the tokenised sentences with some series of strings(what string?) to equalise their lengths before any embedding?

Answer (score 0):

You can compute the maximal separation between
entity mentions linked by a relation and choose an
input width greater than this distance. This will ensure
that every input (relation mention) has same length
by trimming longer sentences and padding shorter
sentences with a special token.